# ASP.NET how to include Eval function inside C# code in aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying this code to get eval function value inside C# code block in aspx page

```
  <%
      string str=Eval("Name").ToString();

     %>
```

but this is an exception Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control how can i do this?
in short i want to get eval function value inside C# block not to control attribute .
want to do something like this

```
<%string str=%><%#Eval("Name")%><%;%>
```

is this available ?
thanks for help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you have done and what do you want?

Comment: @صفي your comment means that i can not do this (last edit in question)?

Answer (score 3):

You use the `#` character to use `Eval` in your page like this.

```
<%# Eval("Name") %>
```

Note: If you just want to include a string in your page, you can do it using the `=` sign.

```
<%= String.Format("{0:#,0.00}", 12345) %>
```

But you can't use `Eval` in the second example.

Comment: pls how can i do this inside <% %>?

Comment: this is databind value so i have to use eval here

Comment: @Esameldean: I just gave you an example of how to do it. My example uses `Eval()` and it used `<% %>`. I have no idea what the problem is, or what else you expect.

Comment: ok but when i complete the code and assign this to variable there is an error.

Comment: @Esameldean you can't assign `Eval` value to another variable in databind control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<%# Eval("Name") %>
```